# Load csv to redshift without passing by S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, import-csv

I am using SQL workbench /J to interact with a redshift cluster and I would like to load a CSV file (about 500k rows) into a redshift table (I do have insert privilege) without using COPY command (as i do not have privileges to copy into s3).

Do you know if it is feasible (using maybe insert), if yes, could you please help me?

Please note that the only privilege i have is : select, insert, update and delete tables within the cluster.

Thanks.

Comment: In my knowledge, you can do this by using python script.

Comment: I know you're asking to do this _without_ S3, but the `copy` command is perfect for this use case. I promise you won't want to do `insert`s with SQL Workbench /J; that will take an infeasible amount of time at 500 K rows. Could you ask your dev-ops people to get you access to an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

**The `COPY` command is the best way to load data into Redshift**. The only other way is to `INSERT` data row by row, which can be done using a python script making use of `pyscopg2` to run `INSERT` SQL queries after establishing a connection to Redshift.

So, just iterate on your CSV file line by line and execute an `INSERT` query over all of rows:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'your_db_name' user= 'your_user' host='redshift_cluster_endpoint_without_port_number' port='port_number' password='password'")
cur = conn.cursor()
for row in rows:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)" %(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]))
```

Where `row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]` is your data for all the columns in a row.

Keep in mind that INSERT row by row will be way slower and less efficient than `COPY` command.

Answer (score -2):

You can COPY command to load data from remote host. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-remote-hosts.html